# Groupby and Count in Pandas based on the value in DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with 3 columns:
`Date`, `Agent` and `Status`.

My column can have 2 status: Accepted or Pending.

I would like to groupby Date and Agent and have the count the number of Accepted

`df.groupby(['Agent', 'Date'])`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `value_counts`

```
s = df.groupby(['Agent', 'Date'])['Status'].value_counts().unstack()
```

Or `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab([df.Agent, df.Date], df.Status)
```

If we only need accepted

```
df['Status'].eq('Accepted').groupby([df['Agent'], df['Date']]).sum()
```